# removed specified string?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

lets see,i have a link image from result of scraping.

e.g: https://xxxx-zzz/zzz/xxx/.png1234w

how i can removed string after ***.png*** meant "**1234w**"

Im tried using rsript() but didn't work
`string.rstrip(".png")`

I dont know what my wrong,im just begging from python

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove the strings after the last '.png', you can do this:

```
s = 'https://xxxx-zzz/zzz/xxx/.png1234w'
print(''.join([s.rsplit('.png', 1)[0], '.png'])
>>>
'https://xxxx-zzz/zzz/xxx/.png'
```

Comment: i got this one,my issue has solved thanks

Comment: how that work if the last .jpg or something?

Answer (score 0):

Can this meet your requirement?

```
>>> url='https://xxxx-zzz/zzz/xxx/.png1234w'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('^(.*\.png).*$', url)
['https://xxxx-zzz/zzz/xxx/.png']
```

Comment: im tried it,but i got [] result of this

Comment: @katrocoplax: Sorry for that. Just have my answer updated.

Comment: no problem about this,my issue has solved

Comment: @katrocoplax: Version does not matter here